# Updating data of Highchart with drilldown in Realtime

Tags: charts, highcharts, polling

[image: Highchart E.g.]

I want to update the Highchart data  in real-time for example suppose i  started drilldown to the level 3 as shown in image below and suppose data shown in that Drilldown level is updated in realtime , then it should  also reflect in that level of chart . also when user drillup using breadcrumb to previous level or any desired level  that particular chart data should also e update as per new realtime data , in sense all 4 level data should be updated irrespective of user at any level of drill down (Provided there shouldn't be any visble chnage/render/re-render animaiton on that chart while updating)

Any solution to do this , in short we want to do a polling on chart.

I am not sure whether this can done or not , as per my experience with chart at certain point we can't

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems to me that it is not possible to do it in the custom way you want. Highcharts are written in such a way that a render is necessary to present updated data, and this cannot be achieved in any other way. And as you wrote, calling render also involves resetting drilldown.